# ¿Como recargar un datatables en angular?

Tags: angular, datatables, datatable, angular-datatables

Quiero que cuando presione cualquier tecla en el campo ***filter_campo*** recargue la tabla, he intentado con `dtOptions.destroy;` y `dtOptions.renderer;` pero ninguno de los 2 recarga la tabla.

Esta es la librería que estoy usando: ***[enlace](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started)***

**categoria.component.html**

```html
<blockquote>Haz clic en alguna fila</blockquote>
<p class="text-danger">Hiciste clic en: <strong>{{ message }}</strong></p>
<div class="row">
    <section class="col-md-12">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-body" style="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="filter_campo" class="control-label col-md-4">Nombre</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" (keyup)="keyNombre($event.target.value)" class="form-control" id="filter_campo" name="filter_campo">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="filter_estados" class="control-label col-md-4">Estado: </label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select id='filter_estados' name='filter_estados' class='form-control'>
                            <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="true">Elija...</option>
                            <option value="true">Activos</option>
                            <option value="false">Inactivos</option>
                            <option value="">Todos</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover"></table>
```

**categoria.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';

import { CategoriaService } from '../services/categoria.service';
import { Categoria } from '../models/categoria';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-categoria',
    templateUrl: '../views/categoria.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../styles/categoria.component.css'],
  providers: [CategoriaService]
})
export class CategoriaComponent implements OnInit {

  message = '';
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

  public id;
  public categoria: Categoria[];

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ){
  }

  someClickHandler(info: any): void {
    this.message = info.id + ' - ' + info.nombre;
  }

  nombre = '';
  status = '';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.listado();
  }

  keyNombre(e){
    this.nombre = e;
    this.dtOptions.destroy;
    this.dtOptions.renderer;
  }

  listado(){
    this.dtOptions = {
      ajax: {
        url: 'http://localhost/webapp-backend/index.php/categorias/listar',
        type: 'POST',
        global: false,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          "json": [
            {
              nombre: this.nombre
            },
            {
              status: this.status
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      columns: [
        {
          data: 0, searchable: false, orderable: false, render: function( data, type, full, meta ){
            return meta.row;
          }
        },
        {
          searchable: false,
          "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
            return row.nombre;
          }
        },
        {
          searchable: false,
          "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
            if(row.status){
              return 'Activo';
            }else{
              return 'Inactivo';
            }
          }
        },
      ],
      order: [[1, 'asc']],
      rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | Object, index: number) => {
        const self = this;
        $('td', row).unbind('click');
        $('td', row).bind('click', () => {
          self.someClickHandler(data);
        });
        return row;
      },
      initComplete: function (data) {
      },
      responsive: true
    };
  }
}
```

***Actualización 1:***

Usando **httpClient**:

**Typescript**:

```
that.http
  .post(
    this.url+'categorias/listar',
    {
        "nombre": this.categorias.nombre,
        "status": this.categorias.status,
    }
  ).subscribe(resp => {

    callback({
      recordsTotal: resp.data.length,
      recordsFiltered: resp.data.length,
      data: resp.data
    });
  });
```

**PHP**:

```
$app->post("/categorias/listar", function() use($app, $db){
    $method = $app->request()->getBody();
    $data = json_decode($method, true);
    $sql  = '';
    $sql .= "SELECT * FROM categorias AS c ";
    if(($data['nombre'] != '')||($data['nombre'] != null)){
        $sql .= "WHERE nombre='".$data['nombre']."'";
    }
    $sql .= " ORDER BY nombre";

    try {

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $tables = [];
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $tables[] = $row;
        }
        $result = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'code' => 200,
            'data' => $tables,
        );
        echo json_encode($result);
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
    }
});
```

El problema que tengo es la paginación:
[image: error]

Comment: Por que usas ajax en vez de un http provider de angular? el codigo deberia ser encapsulado dentro de un servicio retornando un observable.

Comment: @cardeol con **http provider** me daba problemas, no supe como usarlo, si me das un ejemplo adaptado a mi necesidad, pues bienvenido sea.

Comment: @PabloContreras y ya probaste con el filtrado? ==> https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/individual-column-filtering

Comment: *punto aparte* que problemas te daba el http provider?

Comment: @LPZadkiel Voy a probar lo del filtrado a ver.

Comment: @LPZadkiel No recuerdo que problemas me daba, como conseguí poco material para ese modo termine rindiendome y me fui por el modo **ajax**.

Comment: @LPZadkiel Mira mi datatables ([***aquí***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8r3G.png)) y observa cuando intento hacer un filtrado ([***acá***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8piC.png)).

Comment: en teoría debería se un copy paste del método onAfterViewInit, agregaste las sentencias `@ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
  datatableElement: DataTableDirective;`?

Comment: @LPZadkiel, si las agregue, tal cual la guía que me pasaste.

Comment: en tu ejemplo tienes todas las columnas con `searchable: false`, esto es a propósito? me parece que si agregas esto no te buscará en esas columnas y tu lo tienes agregado a todas las columnas

Comment: @LPZadkiel Lo hice a propósito, la intención de hacerle "reset" al datatables es para que obtenga el valor del "input" que esta afuera, como ves el "post" captura el valor del nombre y el status (ambos input fuera del datatables).

Comment: entonces no es un campo de filtro en realidad es un campo de búsqueda, lo que yo te mostré es para filtrar la tabla de los valores que ya tienes, no de los que haya que ir a buscar a la base de datos o dicho de otra forma "filtrar" desde la base de datos

Comment: @LPZadkiel Ok, disculpa haber dicho algo que no es.
Ahora estoy intentando el modo [**Server side the Angular way**](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way), esta vez si me anda, estoy solucionando unos detalles y te digo que tal me fue.
PD: ¿Como envío datos por post con **httpClient**?

Comment: en vez de `get` usas `post` por ejemplo `this.http.post(url, objetoAEnviar, httpOptions);`

Comment: @LPZadkiel siguiendo tu consejo de usar **httpClient**, volví a intentar usarlo y me funciono, ¿como podría solucionar lo de la paginacion?

Comment: @LPZadkiel edite la pregunta y coloque el nuevo código del **httpClient**, el cual solo tengo problema de paginacion.
PD: gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: pues la paginación debería ser automática, ahí si que no se que pueda estar pasando, si te llegan los suficientes registros para que haya mas de una página?

Comment: @LPZadkiel si notas hay 15 registros, y la paginacion esta configurada para 2 en cada pagina (coloque 2 por prueba a ver), de hecho la paginacion da la cant necesaria (15/2=8) pero igual me manda todos los registros en todas las paginaciones.

Comment: @LPZadkiel tampoco ordena los registros cuando uso el ordenamiento de las columnas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basándonos en el ejemplo de  [Custom filtering](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/custom-range-search), creo que te debería funcionar algo así:

```js
export class CategoriaComponent implements OnInit {
    
    message = '';
    dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
    
    datatableElement: DataTableDirective;  // <== 

    keyNombre(e){                          // <== 
      this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        dtInstance.draw();
      });
    }
    
}
```

En cuanto al ordenamiento de columnas, en la definición de las mismas tienes: `"orderable: false"`